# Updating items in spinner corresponding to change in item selected in a previous spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner in my android app. What I want to do is on selection of an item from the spinner I want to show different spinners. E.g. If there are 5 items in my first spinner and I select the second item then a new spinner shall be displayed, show a new of items and the moment I change the item selected on the spinner the items in the next spinner shall change again.

Answer (score 0):

You can define spinner within a Spinner

just hide your other spinner

and show it upon your first spinner actions

like this ...

```
ArrayList<String>list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Main Code

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    list1.add("item1");list1.add("item2");list1.add("item3");list1.add("item4");list1.add("item5");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg2 == 4) {
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }
```